# React Native Navigation - 'cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Trying to navigate to another screen but facing the issue. Code has been given below:

**Routes.js**

```
import { Drawer } from './Drawer';
import { ItemDetailsScreen } from '../screens/ItemDetailsScreen';
enter code here
export const App = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Drawer: { 
            screen: Drawer
        },

        ItemDetails: {
            screen: ItemDetailsScreen
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Drawer",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
)
```

**Drawer.js**

```
export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: ItemListScreen }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
        }) 
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
    }
)
```

When trying to navigate 'ItemDetailsScreen' by calling following methods it shows me the error

```
onItemPress(item) {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'ItemDetailsScreen',
            params: {item: item}
        })
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
    }
```

error is:

> cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Comment: Be sure that your `onItemPress` function is `bind` or use arrow functions. Another problem is that your `routeName` is not `ItemDetailsScreen` it is just `ItemDetails`

Comment: How are you binding your actions to props?